# Unable to concatenate two IEnumerable lists

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api2, ienumerable

I am creating a `WEB API`. I have two `IEnumerable` lists. And at the end I want to concatenate them.

```
IEnumerable result;
IEnumerable prodDetails = new List<tj_xhqd>();
IEnumerable mainDetails= new List<tj_xhqd>();
int prodInterval, prodCount = 0;
int mainInterval, mainCount = 0;

prodCount = giveProdCount(msn, dt);

if(prodCount==0)
{
    prodDetails = "";
}
else if (prodCount<=500)
{
    prodDetails =  mdcEntitites.tj_xhqd
        .Where( m => (m.zdjh == msn) && (m.sjsj >= dt) )
        .Select( x => new { MSN = x.zdjh, PingDateTime = x.sjsj, PingValue = x.xhqd } )
        .ToList();
}
else
{
    prodInterval = prodCount / 500;

    prodDetails = mdcEntitites.tj_xhqd
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Where( m => (m.zdjh == msn) && (m.sjsj >= dt) )
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select( (x, i) => new { MSN = x.zdjh, PingDateTime = x.sjsj, PingValue = x.xhqd, i = i } )
        .Where( x => x.i % prodInterval == 0 )
        .ToList();
}

mainCount = giveMainCount(msn, dt);

if(mainCount==0)
{
    mainDetails = "";
}
else if (mainCount <=500)
{
     mainDetails = kesc.tj_xhqd
        .Where(m => (m.zdjh == msn) && (m.sjsj >= dt))
        .Select(x => new { MSN = x.zdjh, PingDateTime = x.sjsj, PingValue = x.xhqd })
        .ToList();
}
else
{
    mainInterval = mainCount / 500;

    mainDetails = kesc.tj_xhqd
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Where(m => (m.zdjh == msn) && (m.sjsj >= dt))
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select((x, i) => new { MSN = x.zdjh, PingDateTime = x.sjsj, PingValue = x.xhqd, i = i })
        .Where(x => x.i % mainInterval == 0)
        .ToList();
}

if(prodDetails.ToString() == "")
{
    result = mainDetails;
}
else if(mainDetails.ToString()=="")
{
   result = prodDetails;
}
else
{
    result = prodDetails.Concat( mainDetails ); // here I am getting error
}
```

The error is

```
cannot convert from 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.IEnumerable>'
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If both are known to be List<>, why do you use IEnumerable?

Comment: Could you use AddRange() instead of Concat()?

Comment: Change result, prodDetails, and mainDetails from being declared as IEnumerable to being declared as IEnumerable<tj_xhqd>

Comment: `prodDetails = "";` this line won't compile. Have you posted your actual code?

Comment: Also change those ="" as @Dai noted, to = Enumerable.Empty<tj_xhqd>();

Comment: @MineR by doing this I will get `'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type:` error

Comment: This code won't compile anyway - the lists are typed as being of `tj_xhqd` but youe Linq returns anonymous-types which can only be used with `var`.

Comment: @MrFaisal Please replace all of the code in your question with the actual code that compiles - because the code you've posted does not compile at all due to numerous typing errors.

Comment: @Dai it is my actual code

Comment: Rewrite it with a concrete implementation of that anonymous class.

Comment: Have you tried Union , instead of Concat

Comment: The exception isn't related to concat, the whole question isn't about concat. Please adapt the title. You're simply tying to store enumerables of anonymous types into an enumerable of `tj_xhqd` (horrible name, BTW).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the sample program to combine IEnumerable list A and B in to C..
Hope this helps.

```
IEnumerable<int> A = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
IEnumerable<int> B = new List<int>() { 4, 5, 7 };
IEnumerable<int> C = A.Union(B);
```

Comment: Concat isn't the problem, please read the question well.